# Contrast voltage for display from PWM with negative rail

Tags: pwm, lcd, display, negative-voltage

I want to control the contrast of [this](https://www.tme.eu/Document/5e7e3594f8066b341b6293c6d3c9aafb/RC1602B-BIW-CSV.pdf) display using a well-filtered PWM output.
They recommend a potentiometer between Vdd and Vee (negative built-in rail):

[image]

With my MCU I can generate a filtered PWM between Vss and Vdd.
I'm able to shift the voltage using an op-amp.

Here I'm asking if there is a "smarter" way to control the contrast *without* adding an op-amp.

Comment: Generate the PWM, filter it out with an RC low-pass filter having a quite low cut-off frequency (select R in kiloohms range) so that it removes AC (varying) component and the average (DC) component remains. This is basically a crude DAC controlled with duty cycle. Then apply this to the contrast input. You'll have a varying DC with relatively high output resistance.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, yes this is what I was going to do. The question is related to the negative rail.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed the negative voltage requirement. I'll review it and post an update.

Comment: Me too, I missed the negative voltage and I feel daft because I've used these displays before :-) Will delete my answer.

Comment: Alright, sorry I didn't check the datasheet deeply so I don't know what level of negative voltage the display requires. If it's not **lower** than -7V then you can use a 7660-based inverter. If there's no negative voltage laying around then you have to generate it. There are couple of ways but using a switched-capacitor based inverter (e.g. 7660) might be easy and cheap IMO.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I'm able to generate a negative voltage using a 7660 or even with a couple of diodes and caps. The problem is the picture above shows that the pot is connected between Vdd and Vee. That means the output can be either negative or positive...

Comment: If a negative voltage was required only, that would have connected the pot between gnd and Vee.

Comment: I should be dumb or something these days (facepalm). Okay, so if you have a negative voltage it'll be easier to use a variable offset generator. I'm posting an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to have is a negative voltage. Then you can use a simple voltage divider with adjustable voltage to generate the required voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXnCbE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the configuration above you can generate a voltage (Vo-ctrl) between **-VEE / 2** (0% duty-cycle) and **+VEE / 2** (100% duty cycle). Note that

- The frequency of PWM is assumed to be 1 kHz.
- R1+R2 roughly equals to R3.
- The amplitude of the PWM signal is twice the amplitude of -VEE.
- Due to the high capacitances, the settling time might be a bit long (like a few tens of milliseconds).

You can tweak the resistances (or at least, only R3) and voltages in order to get the required range.